# Assign a lambda function to static member variable (c++)

Tags: c++, lambda

I have a template class with a static member variable that I want to be a lambda function. Why doesn't it work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Test {
public:
    static constexpr auto lambda = [](T val) -> T {
        return val;
    };
};

int main() {
    cout << Test<int>::lambda(123) << endl;
}
```

I tried both version with constexpr and const.

In the first case I get:

```
../src/test.cpp:8:24: error: ‘constexpr const Test<int>::<lambda(int)> Test<int>::lambda’, declared using local type ‘const Test<int>::<lambda(int)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
  static constexpr auto lambda = [](T val) -> T {
                        ^~~~~~
```

In the second case:

```
../src/test.cpp:7:20: error: ‘constexpr’ needed for in-class initialization of static data member ‘const Test<int>::<lambda(int)> Test<int>::lambda’ of non-integral type [-fpermissive]
  static const auto lambda = [](T val) -> T {
                    ^~~~~~
../src/test.cpp:7:20: error: ‘const Test<int>::<lambda(int)> Test<int>::lambda’, declared using local type ‘const Test<int>::<lambda(int)>’, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: The 1st case will work fine with C++17.

Comment: Thank you! I will find a work around.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a static function? ...after all there will be different of such for each separate instantiation of `Test`..

Comment: Because I need to refer to the function with a very short name, like n(arg) and variable assignment is a very intuitive concept. Instead, by using a static function the user should define a reference n to Test<int>::myFunction. I didn't even know function reference existed until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A core constant expression may contain a lambda only starting from C++17 (see [cppreference point 8](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression)). This was [proposal N24487](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4487.pdf) and got into C++17 as [P0170R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0170r0.pdf).

If you have to use a static lambda, you can make use of the [construct at first use idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#construct-on-first-use-v2):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Test {
public:
    std::function<T(T)> createLambda() {
        static const std::function<T(T)> returnLambda = [](T val) -> T {
            return val;
        };
        return returnLambda;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<int> lambdaFactory;
    std::function<int(int)> n = lambdaFactory.createLambda();
    std::cout << n(123) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: If you've got C++14 deduced return types, you can probably get rid of the `std::function` wrapper.