# How do I initialize an object using a static member function of that object's class?

Tags: c++

I have a class with some static functions. The class constructor takes a function as one of its arguments.

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    public:
        static std::function<T(T, T)> func1 = [](T a, T b) {
            ...
        }

        static std::function<T(T, T)> func2 = [](T a, T b) {
            ...
        }
     
        MyClass(std::function<T(T, T)> func) {
            ...
        }
}
```

When I initialize an object from this class:

```
MyClass<int> myObj(MyClass.func1);
```

The compiler complains that:

```
> argument list for class template "MyClass" is missing.
```

What is the correct way to do this while keeping the functions in the class itself?

Comment: Did you try `MyClass<int> myObj(MyClass<int>::func1)` ?

Comment: You have to specify the `T` template parameter every time that you want to access it's members: `MyClass<int> myObj(MyClass<int>::func1)`

Comment: [Assign a lambda function to static member variable (c++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014795/assign-a-lambda-function-to-static-member-variable-c) is not a duplicate of this question. There is no issue with creating `static` class members here.

Comment: Those are not static member functions, they are static member variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyClass` is a template not a class. The class that has a static member you want to pass to the constructor is `MyClass<int>`.

Your code has some typos (missing `;`), I had to add `inline` for in-class initialization of the static members, I introduced an alias, and for brevity I used `struct` rather than `class` (the class has only public members):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>


template <typename T>
struct MyClass {
    using fun_t = std::function<T(T,T)>;
    static inline fun_t func1 = [](T a, T b) { return a+b; };
    static inline fun_t func2 = [](T a, T b) { return a-b; };
    fun_t fun;
    MyClass(std::function<T(T, T)> func) : fun(func) {}
};

int main() {
    auto x = MyClass<int>{MyClass<int>::func1};
    std::cout << x.fun(1,2);
}
```

---

As pointed out in comments by AyxanHaqverdili, this would work as well:

```
auto x = MyClass{ MyClass<int>::func1 };
```

due to [CTAD (class template argument deduction)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) where the class templates argument is deduced from the constructors parameters. [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nK44jddP3)

Also this is fine, although a bit hacky, and I don't recommend to actually use it:

```
MyClass<int> x { x.func1 };
```

In a nutshell: You can refer to a variable in its own initializer. We aren't doing something that would require `x` to be fully initialized, so there is no problem with accessing the (already initialized) `static` member via an instance of `MyClass<int>`.  [Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8T8oaKGaE)

A less suspicious variant of this suggested by @HTNW is

```
MyClass<int> x{decltype(x)::func1};
```

Now it is more obvious that we only use the type of `x` and access a static member of its class.

Comment: [MyClass{ MyClass<int>::func1 };](https://godbolt.org/z/nK44jddP3) also works.

Comment: So does [MyClass<int> x { x.func1 };](https://godbolt.org/z/8T8oaKGaE)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili good point about CTAD, though its kind of orthogonal, and would require more explanation. And the latter is also interesting, but nasty ;). I'll give it a try...

Comment: I would honestly consider `MyClass<int> x{x.func1};` or `MyClass<int> x{decltype(x)::func1};` as preferred. It ensures `func1` comes from the right class even if the type of `x` changes and it clearly states the type of `x`.

Comment: @HTNW I dont like `MyClass<int> x{x.func1};` because one has to inspect the class to see that it is not a problem. With `MyClass<int> x{decltype(x)::func1};` its both obvious, we only care about `x`s type and access a static member of the class.

Comment: LOL. In fact I tried using `MyClass<int>.func1` but it didn't work. Did too much java to the point I forgot static members are referred to by a double colon :) Thank you!

Comment: @WaisKamal there is no `MyClass<int>.func1`. Its either `x.func1` or `MyClass<int>::func1`